# How can I save user response time in a quiz?

Tags: jquery, timer

I am writing a quiz application, the ui of which looks like this. [image]

My question is how to save the time user took to answer every question? The user can come back and visit any question later using the question palette on the sidebar. In that case, I want to add both the times. The timer you see is done with `setInterval()` function. I tried adding a count variable to count the number of seconds spent on every question, but that didn't work well. Please suggest a better alternative.

Comment: You need to use server side logic for this.

Comment: I am inexperienced with server load. If I have 300 simultaneous users and save time for everyone per question, will the server be able to handle it easily?

Comment: Ah... No no.. Don't use Server Side code then... But you meant that the client will be closing the browser and coming back right?

Comment: No, I meant they can use the question palette to visit the same question again. For example: Mark it for review. I want to count all the time spent viewing a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When question appears:

```
var startTime = $.now();
```

when user answers:

```
var endTime = $.now();
```

Response time:

```
var responseTime = endTime - startTime
```

Comment: Eh... `Uncaught TypeError: $.now is not a function(…)`

Comment: use jquery 1.12.4

Comment: and divide it by 1000 to scale it in seconds, $.now() returns in milliseconds

Comment: In place of `$.now()` I decided to use the `Date()` function. And then calculated the number of seconds using: `var elapsed = parseInt((endTime - startTime) / 1000);` This works with all recent jquery versions.